# Java - Android - Accessing the /data/data folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm writing an application to get a person's ID from a game and it is stored in

```
/data/data/AppName/shared_prefs/AppName.xml
```

I was writing a method to access the PlayerPrefs but it according to my program the file doesn't exist.

```
private void AccessPlayerPrefs() //TODO: Refactor this method.
{
    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File internalStorage = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if(externalStorage.canWrite())
    {
        String currentDBPath = "/data/com.outerminds.tubular/shared_prefs/com.outerminds.tubular.xml"; //
        String backupDBPath = "/Video/appname_backup.xml";
        File currentDB = new File(internalStorage, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(externalStorage, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()).setNegativeButton("Okay", null).create().show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("It doesn't exist.").setNegativeButton("Okay", null).create().show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Can't write").setNegativeButton("Okay", null).create().show();
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me resolve this issue.